# Why is BeautifulSoup unable to correctly read/parse this RSS (XML) document?

Tags: python, xml, rss, beautifulsoup

YCombinator is nice enough to provide an [RSS feed](http://news.ycombinator.com/rss) and a [big RSS feed](http://news.ycombinator.com/bigrss) containing the top items on [HackerNews](http://news.ycombinator.com/). I am trying to write a python script to access the RSS feed document and then parse out certain pieces of information using BeautifulSoup. However, I am getting some strange behavior when BeautifulSoup tries to get the content of each of the items.

Here are a few sample lines of the RSS feed:

```
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Hacker News</title><link>http://news.ycombinator.com/</link><description>Links for the intellectually curious, ranked by readers.</description>
<item>
    <title>EFF Patent Project Gets Half-Million-Dollar Boost from Mark Cuban and &#39;Notch&#39;</title>
    <link>https://www.eff.org/press/releases/eff-patent-project-gets-half-million-dollar-boost-mark-cuban-and-notch</link>
    <comments>http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4944322</comments>
    <description><![CDATA[<a href="http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4944322">Comments</a>]]></description>
</item>
<item>
    <title>Two Billion Pixel Photo of Mount Everest (can you find the climbers?)</title>
    <link>https://s3.amazonaws.com/Gigapans/EBC_Pumori_050112_8bit_FLAT/EBC_Pumori_050112_8bit_FLAT.html</link>
    <comments>http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4943361</comments>
    <description><![CDATA[<a href="http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4943361">Comments</a>]]></description>
</item>
...
</channel>
</rss>
```

Here is the code I have written (in python) to access this feed and print out the `title`, `link`, and `comments` for each item:

```
import sys
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

request = requests.get('http://news.ycombinator.com/rss')
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text)
items = soup.find_all('item')
for item in items:
    title = item.find('title').text
    link = item.find('link').text
    comments = item.find('comments').text
    print title + ' - ' + link + ' - ' + comments
```

However, this script is giving output that looks like this:

```
EFF Patent Project Gets Half-Million-Dollar Boost from Mark Cuban and &#39;Notch&#39; -  - http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4944322
Two Billion Pixel Photo of Mount Everest (can you find the climbers?) -  - http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4943361
...
```

As you can see, the middle item, `link`, is somehow being omitted. That is, the resulting value of `link` is somehow an empty string. So why is that?

As I dig into what is in `soup`, I realize that it is somehow choking when it parses the XML. This can be seen by looking at at the first item in `items`:

```
>>> print items[0]
<item><title>EFF Patent Project Gets Half-Million-Dollar Boost from Mark Cuban and &#39;Notch&#39;</title></link>https://www.eff.org/press/releases/eff-patent-project-gets-half-million-dollar-boost-mark-cuban-and-notch<comments>http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4944322</comments><description>...</description></item>
```

You'll notice that something screwy is happening with just the `link` tag. It just gets the close tag and then the text for that tag after it. This is some very strange behavior especially in contrast to `title` and `comments` being parsed without a problem.

This seems to be a problem with BeautifulSoup because what is actually read in by requests doesn't have any problems with it. I don't think it is limited to BeautifulSoup though because I tried using xml.etree.ElementTree API as well and the same problem arose (is BeautifulSoup built on this API?).

Does anyone know why this would be happening or how I can still use BeautifulSoup without getting this error?

Note: I was finally able to get what I wanted with xml.dom.minidom, but this doesn't seem like a highly recommended library. I would like to continue using BeautifulSoup if possible.

**Update**: I am on a Mac with OSX 10.8 using Python 2.7.2 and BS4 4.1.3.

**Update 2**: I have lxml and it was installed with pip. It is version 3.0.2. As far as libxml, I checked in /usr/lib and the one that shows up is libxml2.2.dylib. Not sure when or how that was installed.

Comment: Are you sure this is the actual RSS? Because I just tested it with `ElementTree`, `cElementTree`, and the `lxml` implementation, and they all got the `link` nodes just fine. So, either you did something wrong with `xml.etree.ElementTree`, or you didn't give us the right input data.

Comment: Also, what versions of Python and BS4 are you using? (And do you have lxml installed, and if so, what versions of libxml and lxml?) I just did a clean install of Python 3.3.0 and BS4 4.1.3, and it was able to parse that RSS just fine. And with Apple Python 2.7.2 and BS4 4.1.3, again, no problem.

Comment: @abarnert I have used both requests and urllib2 to pull directly from http://news.ycombinator.com/rss. So unless there is something wrong with what ycombinator is providing, I don't know what the issue with the RSS could be.

Comment: Well, did you get the RSS above by copying and pasting directly from the same thing your code is seeing? Or is it possible that there was a broken RSS feed for a while that your code ran into, but by the time you grabbed it to paste it here, it was fixed? (The fact that jdotjdot sees the same problem with your pasted code implies that it's actually something wrong with both of your versions of BS4, not with that RSS, but I didn't know that at the time I asked.)

Comment: Also, what platform are you on?

Comment: Thanks for listing the platform and BS4 version. But what about the lxml question? Do you have it, if so what version and how was it installed, and which libxml are you using, and if not Apple's built-in `/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib` what version is _that_ and how was it installed?

Comment: you can try feedparser http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/

Comment: @abarnert See my update, does this give you anymore ideas about this issue?

Comment: Looks like you never found an answer? I recently ran into a similar problem that for some reason was fixed by using the html5lib parser. I have no idea why, but you might try that if you haven't already.

Comment: Please see the answers below about using the correct parser ('xml') and "accept" one of those as the correct answer.  I recommend this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28782300/82114

Answer (score 7):

Wow, great question.  This strikes me as a bug in BeautifulSoup.  The reason that you can't access the link using `soup.find_all('item').link` is that when you first load the html into BeautifulSoup to begin with, it does something odd to the HTML:

```py
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
>>> BS(html)
<html><body><rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Hacker News</title><link/>http://news.ycombinator.com/<description>Links
for the intellectually curious, ranked by readers.</description>
<item>
<title>EFF Patent Project Gets Half-Million-Dollar Boost from Mark Cuban and 'No
tch'</title>
<link/>https://www.eff.org/press/releases/eff-patent-project-gets-half-million-d
ollar-boost-mark-cuban-and-notch
    <comments>http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4944322</comments>
<description>Comments]]&gt;</description>
</item>
<item>
<title>Two Billion Pixel Photo of Mount Everest (can you find the climbers?)</ti
tle>
<link/>https://s3.amazonaws.com/Gigapans/EBC_Pumori_050112_8bit_FLAT/EBC_Pumori_
050112_8bit_FLAT.html
    <comments>http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4943361</comments>
<description>Comments]]&gt;</description>
</item>
...
</channel>
</rss></body></html>
```

Look carefully--it has actually changed the first `<link>` tag to `<link/>` and then removed the `</link>` tag.  I'm not sure why it would do this, but without fixing the problem in the `BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup` class initialization, you're not going to be able to use it for now.

#### Update:

I think your best (albeit hack-y) bet for now is to use the following for `link`:

```
>>> soup.find('item').link.next_sibling
u'http://news.ycombinator.com/'
```

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that it is messing up the `link` tags and after narrowing it down, it seems like this must be something with BeautifulSoup (or dependencies of BS). Any thoughts on what is going on under the hood or how to fix this?

Comment: @Treebranch no idea yet what's going on or how to fix, but gave you a band-aid

Comment: @jdotjdot: What version of BS4 are you using? As I mentioned in the comments to the question, with a brand new install of BS4 4.1.3 on both a clean Python.org 3.3.0 and Apple's pre-installed 2.7.2, I don't see this bug.

Comment: @abarnert I'm using BS4 4.1.3

Comment: As I asked Treebranch, do you have lxml installed? If so, which versions of libxml and lxml (and how were they installed)? Because IIRC, BS tries to use lxml if it's available. Oh, and what platform.

Comment: Also, you workaround doesn't do the right thing when BS4 _doesn't_ have a problem. So, you probably need to conditionalize the workaround in some way.

Comment: That's correct--like I said, it's just a hacky thing to try to temporarily solve his problem.  Better is to figure out the issue with bs4 in the first place.

Comment: It would help track things down if you would answer the questions I asked. I suspect the bug is in either some older version of some relevant library that you both have while I have the newer version, or in something weird you both did installing something. But without knowing what you have or how you installed it, it's impossible to debug.

Comment: `lxml` 2.3.6 is what I have

Comment: @jdotjdot: That's something… although it would be more helpful if you'd answer _all_ of the questions, instead of just answering one at a time. What version of libxml, how did you get them, what platform are you on, etc.? Otherwise, if it turns out this isn't a known bug that was fixed between lxml 2.3.6 and lxml 3.0.2, we have to go back to square zero and look for the next thing.

Comment: @jdotjdot: Wait a second… Where did you get a 2.3.6? http://lxml.de lists 2.3.5 as the last 2.x version!

Comment: @Abarnet sorry, can't be on SO all the time, have a pretty busy job so I glance at it when I can.  I don't know how I have 2.3.6, but that's what `pip freeze` claims.  I don't have `libxml` as far as I can tell.  On Windows 7, latest python 2.7.

Comment: @jdotjdot: I don't think it's possible to have `lxml` without `libxml`. At least not a working copy I have no idea what `libxml` is actually called on Windows (`libxml.dll`? `libxml2.dll`? `xml2.dll`? who knows…), or where to look for it. Maybe it was even static-linked into `lxml` somehow? But since `lxml` is just a binding for `libxml` (and `libxslt`), it has to be there in some form.

Comment: @jdotjdot: And as for not being on SO all the time, that's exactly why I wanted you to answer all of the questions at once, since it's anywhere from 15 minutes to 16 hours between my seeing your answer and asking the next question, and likewise for you answering…

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the problem seems to be related with the parser you are using.  By default, a HTML one is used.  Try using soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'xml') after installing the lxml module.

It will then use a XML parser instead of a HTML one and it should be all ok.

See http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser for more info

Comment: had a feeling it was the lxml parser doing this.

Answer (score 3):

@Yan Hudon is right .I have solved the problem with `soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'xml')`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a bug in BeautifulSoup here.

I installed a clean copy of BS4 4.1.3 on Apple's stock 2.7.2 from OS X 10.8.2, and everything worked as expected. It doesn't mis-parse the `<link>` as `</link>`, and therefore it doesn't have the problem with the `item.find('link')`.

I also tried using the stock `xml.etree.ElementTree` and `xml.etree.cElementTree` in 2.7.2, and `xml.etree.ElementTree` in python.org 3.3.0, to parse the same thing, and it again worked fine. Here's the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

rss = ET.fromstring(x)
for channel in rss.findall('channel'):
  for item in channel.findall('item'):
    title = item.find('title').text
    link = item.find('link').text
    comments = item.find('comments').text
    print(title)
    print(link)
    print(comments)
```

I then installed lxml 3.0.2 (I believe BS uses lxml if available), using Apple's built-in `/usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib` (which, according to `xml2-config --version`, is 2.7.8), and did the same tests using its etree, and using BS, and again, everything worked.

In addition to screwing up the `<link>`, jdotjdot's output shows that BS4 is screwing up the `<description>` in an odd way. The original is this:

```
<description><![CDATA[<a href="http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4944322">Comments</a>]]></description>
```

His output is:

```
<description>Comments]]&gt;</description>
```

My output from running his exact same code is:

```
<description><![CDATA[<a href="http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4944322">Comments</a>]]></description>
```

So, it seems like there's a much bigger problem going on here. The odd thing is that it's happening to two different people, when it isn't happening on a clean install of the latest version of anything.

That implies either that it's a bug that's been fixed and I just have a newer version of whatever had the bug, or it's something weird about the way they both installed something.

BS4 itself can be ruled out, since at least Treebranch has 4.1.3 just like me. Although, without knowing how he installed it, it could be a problem with the installation.

Python and its built-in etree can be ruled out, since at least Treebranch has the same stock Apple 2.7.2 from OS X 10.8 as me.

It could very well be a bug with lxml or the underlying libxml, or the way they were installed. I know jdotjdot has lxml 2.3.6, so this could be a bug that's been fixed somewhere between 2.3.6 and 3.0.2. In fact, given that, according to the [lxml website](http://lxml.de) and the change notes for any version after 2.3.5, there *is* no 2.3.6, so whatever he has may be some kind of buggy release from very early on a canceled branch or something… I don't know his libxml version, or how either was installed, or what platform he's on, so it's hard to guess, but at least this is something that can be investigated.