# Reading <content:encoded> tags using BeautifulSoup 4

Tags: python, rss, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup 4 (bs4) to read an XML RSS feed, and have come across the following entry.  I'm trying to read the content enclosed in the `<content:encoded><![CDATA[...]]</content>` tag:

```
<item>
    <title>Foobartitle</title>
    <link>http://www.acme.com/blah/blah.html</link>
    <category><![CDATA[mycategory]]></category>
    <description><![CDATA[The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog]]></description>
    <content:encoded>
        <![CDATA[<p><img class="feature" src="http://www.acme.com/images/image.jpg" alt="" /></p>]]>
    </content:encoded>
</item>
```

As I understand it, this format is part of the [RSS content module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/RSS/Article/Why_RSS_Content_Module_is_Popular_-_Including_HTML_Contents) and is pretty common.

I'd like to isolate the `<content:encoded>` tag and then read the CDATA contents.
For the avoidance of doubt, the result would be `<p><img class="feature" src="http://www.acme.com/images/image.jpg" alt="" /></p>`.

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032172/how-can-i-grab-cdata-out-of-beautifulsoup/2032252#2032252), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2032172/how-can-i-grab-cdata-out-of-beautifulsoup), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961831/why-is-beautifulsoup-unable-to-correctly-read-parse-this-rss-xml-document) stackoverflow post but I've not been able to figure out how to get the job done since they are not directly related to my case.

I am using the [lxml XML](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) parser with bs4.

Any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: The reason for the answers your referencing won't work for you is because bs4 strips the CDATA tag away as described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16426507/can-cdata-sections-be-preserved-by-beautifulsoup?rq=1 and so any reference to CDATA after the soup is made is pointless. BeautifulSoup 3 does not do this and so the answer given in your reference is good for that version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

doc = ...
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, "xml")  # Directs bs to use lxml
```

Interestingly, BeautifulSoup/lxml changes the tags around, noticeably from `content:encoded` to simply `encoded`.

```
>>> print soup
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item>
<title>Foobartitle</title>
<link>http://www.acme.com/blah/blah.html</link>
<category>mycategory</category>
<description>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog</description>
<encoded>
        &lt;p&gt;&lt;img class="feature" src="http://www.acme.com/images/image.jpg" alt="" /&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
    </encoded>
</item>
```

From there, it should do to just parse through the children.

```
for encoded_content in soup.findAll("encoded"):
    for child in encoded_content.children:
        print child
```

That results in `<p><img class="feature" src="http://www.acme.com/images/image.jpg" alt="" /></p>`. Note, this seems to be an instance of `bs4.element.NavigableString`, not CData like in your linked answers.

Comment: Oliver, thanks for the quick response! The weird content:encoded -> encoded tag change was what I was missing.