# Python can't scrape tag link

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am using python 3.7 and BeautifulSoup to scrape Wordpress feeds. I am not able to scrape data from the link tag. All other tags works. If I rename the tag, it works. Here is a stripped xml example -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<site xmlns="com-wordpress:feed-additions:1">12345</site>
    <item>
        <title>My title</title>
        <link>https://test.com/test/</link>
        <linktest>https://test.com/test/</linktest>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

If I parsed like this -

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('./sources/falskanyheter.xml', 'r'), 'lxml')
print(soup.prettify())
```

I got the result -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
 <body>
  <rss version="2.0">
   <channel>
    <site xmlns="com-wordpress:feed-additions:1">
     12345
    </site>
    <item>
     <title>
      My title
     </title>
     <link/>
     https://test.com/test/
     <linktest>
      https://test.com/test/
     </linktest>
    </item>
   </channel>
  </rss>
 </body>
</html>
```

The link / url is not in the link tag and can't be parsed with for example - tag.link.text

Comment: Did you check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961831/why-is-beautifulsoup-unable-to-correctly-read-parse-this-rss-xml-document/28782300 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switch the lxml to xml in the open function and it works. I thought I had test that but when I did I probably had an other error also. Well, it works - thanks to me and great answer.

Answer (score 0):

congratulations! Here is another method for reference only.

```
from simplified_scrapy import SimplifiedDoc

html = '''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0">
<channel>
<site xmlns="com-wordpress:feed-additions:1">12345</site>
    <item>
        <title>My title</title>
        <link>https://test.com/test/</link>
        <linktest>https://test.com/test/</linktest>
    </item>
</channel>
</rss>
'''
doc = SimplifiedDoc(html)
nodes = doc.select('item').children
print([(node.tag,node.text) for node in nodes])
```

Result:

```
[('title', 'My title'), ('link', None), ('linktest', 'https://test.com/test/')]
```